# Array can't take values from variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I try run this code but I have on page in all this 35 fields value "undefined" I try print on screen this letters

```
ar letters_tab = new Array(35);
var letters = "AĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻ";
for(var i in letters)
{
     letters_tab.push[i];
}
```

Comment: you could just do `.split`.

Comment: `letters_tab = "AĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻ".split("");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate through a string using `for..in` like the way you demonstrate.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but here are a few options:

### 1.  [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

If you're just trying to get the string into a character array, this will do:

```
var letters_tab = 'AĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻ'.split('');
```

### 2. Manual iteration

If you want to manually iterate through the string to construct the array, you can also do so by using a plain old [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop:

```
var letters_tab = []; // alternatively, new Array()
var letters = "AĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻ";
for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
{
     letters_tab.push(letters[i]);
}
```

### 3.  [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

You can also iterate a string using a `for..of` loop in modern JavaScript environments:

```
var letters_tab = []; // alternatively, new Array()
for (var i of 'AĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻ') {
    letters_tab.push(i);
}
```

Comment: Yes I wan't split letters and print them like You show me in this method.
Thank You :)

Comment: @Darek Glad I could help. If this answer worked for you, please make sure you accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can manually go through the strings and get characters from it and put it into your array.

**try this:**

```
var letters_tab = new Array(35);
var letters = "AĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻ";
for(var i=0; i < letters.length; i++)
{
    letters_tab[i] = letters.charAt(i);
}
alert(letters.letters_tab);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
for (var letter in letters) {
    letters_tab.push(letters[letter]);
}
```

That's because the variable `letter` is only the index, not the actual value.

You can also use the `.split` method.

```
var letters_tab = 'AĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻ'.split('');
```